# Worklight Direct Update keeps executing

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, auto-update

I have a Hybrid application running WL 6.2 on my iPhone 5 (ios 8.1). When I launch the application it starts the UPDATE process as might be expected. However, it does this EVERY time I launch the app - even though I haven't updated anything on the server.

When I loaded the .wlapp file and the WL console says that it uploaded successfully. On the iPhone, there are no errors or even a suggestion that something may have gone wrong.

I would appreciate any thoughts - i don't know where to start!

Some additional information:

I'm using WL Studio on a MAC (OSX 10.9.5)
WL Studio is version 6.2.0.00-20140825-1637
The server (please don't laugh) is running on Windows 7 enterprise - it's actually the Liberty instance that's part of WL Studio. It's just a laptop sitting next to me. Clearly not a production setup.

I will say that until just recently (past day or so) this has been working as expected. The updates installed ONLY ONCE after a new wlapp file was uploaded.

Comment: Start by mentioning where is this happening - development server or qa/production? if qa/production, do you have more than one server running in your setup? also edit the question and provide full & exact steps from build (where are you building) to deploying (how are you deploying). also mention if there is any mix with OS (like building on mac and deploying on windows) or alike.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing latest worklight studio released on Oct 27th

[IBM Worklight Studio V6.2.0.1](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-worklight-studio#.VFsRoPnF9sM)

Also change your directUpdate mode to default i.e. perSession.

Cheers !!

Comment: Thanks (all). Sorry for the tardy response - traveling. It would appear that it is related to the WL Studio version as I can not replicate the problem on a newer install. When I get a chance to refresh the other laptop, I'll verify and comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps in order to alleviate this issue:

1. Delete the app from the device
2. Close eclipse, open the workspace folder and delete the WorklightServerConfig folder
3. Open eclipse and deploy the application to the server and device

Comment: I follow these steps but still direct update is coming every time close and open the application. Any help you can do here appreciated.